# Spring AOP change value of methods argument on around advice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

Is it possible to change method argument value on basis of some check before executing using Spring AOP

**My method**

```
public String doSomething(final String someText, final boolean doTask) {
    // Some Content
    return "Some Text";
}
```

**Advice method**

```
public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    String methodName = methodInvocation.getMethod().getName();

    Object[] arguments = methodInvocation.getArguments();
    if (arguments.length >= 2) {
        if (arguments[0] instanceof String) {
            String content = (String) arguments[0];
            if(content.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                // Set my second argument as false
            } else {
                // Set my second argument as true
            }
        }
    }
    return methodInvocation.proceed();
}
```

Please suggest me the way to set the method argument value as there is no setter options for the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer using `MethodInvocation`

```
public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    String methodName = methodInvocation.getMethod().getName();

    Object[] arguments = methodInvocation.getArguments();
    if (arguments.length >= 2) {
        if (arguments[0] instanceof String) {
            String content = (String) arguments[0];
            if(content.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                if (methodInvocation instanceof ReflectiveMethodInvocation) {
                    ReflectiveMethodInvocation invocation = (ReflectiveMethodInvocation) methodInvocation;
                    arguments[1] = false;
                    invocation.setArguments(arguments);
                }
            } else {
                if (methodInvocation instanceof ReflectiveMethodInvocation) {
                    ReflectiveMethodInvocation invocation = (ReflectiveMethodInvocation) methodInvocation;
                    arguments[1] = true;
                    invocation.setArguments(arguments);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return methodInvocation.proceed();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Yes that's possible. You need a [`ProceedingJoinPoint`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint.html#proceed(java.lang.Object[])) and instead of:

```
methodInvocation.proceed();
```

you can then call proceed with the new arguments, for example:

```
methodInvocation.proceed(new Object[] {content, false});
```

see http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-proceeding-with-the-call

Comment: Just be careful: these things are easily skipped during refactoring. If you don't have nice test suite it can hurt.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! The arguments have to match and the refactoring tools are not going to help for such cases.

Comment: But I used MethodInterceptor interface. What changes I have to make for ProceedingJoinPoint

Comment: Did you try to change the interface to `ProceedingJoinPoint`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Spring AOP, create point cut using `@Around`.
Then you can use the below code to change the arguments of the method, based on the condition.

```
int index = 0;
Object[] modifiedArgs = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();

for (Object arg : proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
    if (arg instanceof User) {    // Check on what basis argument have to be modified.
        modifiedArgs[index]=user;
       }
    index++;
}
return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(modifiedArgs);  //Continue with the method with modified arguments.
```